# How to get Controls which are partially contained in a given rectangle

Tags: c#, controls, selection

I iterate over my form and "select" all the controls contained with a give rectangle.  I use the following:

```
    List<Control> getControls(Control container, Rectangle rect)
    {
        rect = RectangleToClient(rect);

        controlSelection = new List<Control>();

        foreach (Control ctl in container.Controls)
            if (rect.Contains(ctl.Bounds))
            {
                controlSelection.Add(ctl);
                foreach (Control ct in ctl.Controls) controlSelection.Add(ct);
            }

        return controlSelection;
    }
```

How can I change it, to select a control even it's just barely within that given rectangle?

Comment: Use `IntersectsWith()` instead of `Contains()`.